# snap install of hugo yields snap-confine elevation error

Tags: 16.04, snap

I'm trying to install hugo on 16.04. The regular apt-get install version is pretty old, so I figured I'd try using a snap for the first time. So, I issue

`snap install hugo`

It seems to work great, but when I try to run it, I get this error:

`snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks`

I've googled on the error and see it coming up in lots of places; one suggestion was to try reinstalling snapd, which I did. No such luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the output of `snap version`?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the snap-confine profile is not loaded as suggested by [this](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-confine-has-elevated-permissions-error/2391/3). Snapd is dependant on the kernel version. I suspect if you install an Ubuntu kernel (eg: linux-generic (4.4)) and reboot, it will work.

Use [this](https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/) guide to install another kernel.

Comment: While the second link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I'm using a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 install:

`$ uname -r` yields
`4.6.0-040600-generic`

... is there reason that should be insufficient?

Comment: I really don't why 4.6.0 generic would cause a problem, but I guess you should try another version.

Comment: Hmm -- guess I'm uninspired to move off the standard distribution kernel for the sake of installing a snap. This must be a bug in 16.04, no?